# Report on Actual GC Settings in JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How can I report on the GC settings from java?  I know that I *RuntimeMXBean* can report input args via *getInputArguments()* and I could use that to report the settings.  I'd rather interrogate the GC object and report on the actual settings there.

Is there a way to access these settings from within a java application?

The following command shows all kinds of setting which I'm not setting and I want to write a small app to verify the veracity of these settings

```
java -XX+PrintCommandLineFlags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get list of flags is though `jcmd` MBean.

Snippet below prints JVM XX flags

```
public class GetFlags {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedObjectNameException {

        MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        ObjectName name = ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand");

        DiagnosticCommand_vmFlags vmFlags = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(server, name, DiagnosticCommand_vmFlags.class);

        System.out.println("Short version");
        System.out.println(vmFlags.vmFlags());

        System.out.println("Verbose version");
        System.out.println(vmFlags.vmFlags("-all"));
    }


    public interface DiagnosticCommand_vmFlags {

        public String vmFlags(String... args);

    }
}
```